# Gradle Root Project: Unnecessary Empty JAR Generation

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, project, root

I am working on a Gradle multi-project build with four Java sub-projects. I recently decided to centralize the dependency declarations for these sub-projects within the `build.gradle.kts`
of the root project. This approach has been successful in managing dependencies across my projects.

However, I have encountered an annoying issue. When I build the project, a build folder is generated in the root project directory, and within it, an empty JAR file is created, containing only a manifest file. The root project has no source code and is merely a directory for managing the sub-projects. Also an empty code coverage report folder is generated in the build folder, even if there's no code.

My question is twofold:

- Why is Gradle generating an empty JAR and a build folder for the root project, which contains no source code?
- How can I configure Gradle to treat the root project as a non-Java project, as a bare project?

**Root Project Configuration**

`settings.gradle.kts` file:

```
rootProject.name = "root
include("core")
include("app")
include("ui")
```

`build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("jacoco")
}

configure(subprojects) {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    plugins.apply("java")
    plugins.apply("jacoco")

    dependencies {
        implementation(platform("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-bom:2.20.0"))
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core")
        implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl")
        implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32")
        testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0"))
        testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
        testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
    }

    tasks.test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    tasks.jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn(tasks.test)
    }

    tasks.jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        dependsOn(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
    }
}
```

Your insights and suggestions on how to configure Gradle to treat the root project appropriately would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I tried to use `apply false` for each plugin, but it's an error, they are core plugins.

```
plugins {
    id("java") apply false
    id("jacoco") apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("jacoco")
}
```

Since these are core plugins, this is *only* useful if you want to apply them to the current project. Just remove these lines if the root project is not meant to produce a jar.

Comment: I've already tried this, but removing plugins leads to this error: "Unresolved reference: implementation". Seems that implementation needs java plugin because it's defined by this plugin.

Comment: The whole idea is to have common dependencies in the root project. Removing plugins defeats this purpose, I would go back to adding the same dependencies to each sub-project.